# What is wrong with these function calls? Nodejs

Tags: javascript

I made 2 functions to import data from the json file into the db but doesn't work only if I call the importData function alone. But if I call deleteData then importData the db is empty.

```
 const tours = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/tours-simple.json`, 'utf-8')
);


const deleteData = async () => {
  try {
    await Tour.deleteMany();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Import data into db
const importData = async () => {
  try {
    await Tour.create(tours);
    console.log('Data successfully loaded!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

deleteData();
importData();
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is there a list of templates similar to that statement somewhere or did you build these on your own?

Comment: @GottZ - Built them on my own over time. I should do a repo. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please do! this not only helps OP but us who complain too!

Comment: apart from that, what IS `Tour`. your own class? an instance of a known database connector? what connector? please provide anything that is required to reproduce this issue. also.. is `tours` in the surrounding scope?

Comment: This question is really simple and on point, idk why it's closed, lmao. I just said importData works if I call it without deleteData..

Comment: Where does `tour` come from in `importData`? Also note that when you call an `async` function, you must either `await` it or use `.then`/`.catch` on it if you want to wait for its result. Otherwise, you just get back a promise and the work isn't done yet. For instance, in your calls at the end of your code block, the work `deleteData` does won't be finished yet when you call `importData`.

Comment: It was almost certainly closed because at least three people saw it with a picture of code rather than actual code, which means it lacked sufficient detail. One of those people (me) has now voted to reopen.

Comment: @T.J Crowder Thank you, I had to use then after deleteData call and call importData.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 functions arent synchronouse. Well they are inside sync but not for the outside world. You could wrap it in an IIFE:

```
(async () => {
   await deleteData();
   await importData()
})()
```

Or with `.then()`

```
deleteData().then(importData).then(()=>console.log('done'))
```

`async` means the function returns an promise. So you should treat them like promises

Comment: Don't need to wrap a promise returning function. It's better to do: `deleteData().then(importData).then(()=>console.log('done'))` It's the reason promises were invented in the first place - to avoid many nested callbacks

Comment: Actually, a neat trick to get nice formatting would be: `Promise.resolve().then(deleteData).then(importData).then(()=>console.log('done'))`

Comment: @slebetman not bad, i am gonna update it. hmm why the `Promise.resolve()` ?

Comment: To get the promise chain started so you can indent both `deleteData` and `importData` nicely. It doesn't add any utility and in fact delays your code execution unnecessarily by one event loop but allows you to have nice looking code